# Overwrite model's save

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I try to overwrite an ember-data model's save function:

**models/client.js**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  billingAddress: DS.belongsTo('address'),
  //...
  save: function(...arg){
    var _this = this;
    this.get('billingAddress').then(billingAddress=>{
      return billingAddress.save().then(function(){
        return _this._super(arg);
      });
    })

  }
});
```

Somewhere else I do

```
record.save().then(function(){
  // show a message
});
```

I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

**SOLUTION**

The main problem was that calling `super` from a promise is not that straight forward, but **is possible**:

```
  save: function(...arg){
    let _super = this._super;
    return somePromise.then(() => _super.call(this));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a common pattern but I wouldn't overwrite the model's save method, instead I would handle it on the level of the route/controller.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const { Mixin, RSVP: { resolve } } = Ember;

Ember.Mixin.create({
  beforeSave() {
    return resolve();
  },
  save() {
    this.beforeSave().then(() => this.get('currentModel').save());
  },
  {
    actions: {
      save() {
        this.save();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

You would add that mixin to your routes, if you add it to the controller `currentModel` becomes `model`, and overwrite `beforeSave` to deal with your relationships, make sure you return a promise from `beforeSave`.

Comment: thanks! the problem that I use route-action for 'save'. It means all 'save' action from the template button runs into one central place (application route). It checks if the record isNew? if yes, then clones it (it clears the form), and show a message to the user. If not, then just simple saves it and shows an update message. I dont really want to do this things over and over again in the controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Your Save implementation does not return anything.
I think you have to return the promise returned from "_this._super(arg);"

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  billingAddress: DS.belongsTo('address'),
  //...
  save: function(...arg){
    var _this = this;
    return this.get('billingAddress').then(billingAddress=>{
      return billingAddress.save().then(function(){
        return _this._super(arg);
      });
    })

  }
});
```

Comment: thanks, but the network traffic shows only one POST (to the address endpoint), it seems client save never fires.

Comment: You can't return super from inside a promise

Comment: @Kitler hmm. Is there any solution / workaround for this? I think it is a valid use case: save some relationships before I save the main model.

Comment: you could handle that in an action. Save you main model and then your relationships.